# Separate products in different sub categories on the page with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4.2

I've made ability for administrator to create multiple categories under sub-categories. Now I want to show each product assigned to category.

The problem is that each sub-sub category show same product. Most probably the problem lays in database and the way they are stored but I'm not sure where exactly

So far this is my controller

```
public function showCategoryInfo($subcatId) {

$dual = DualSubCategories::where('sub_cat_id', '=', $subcatId)->get();
$dual_products = DualSubCategories::with('products')->findOrFail( $subcatId );  

    $subcat1 = SubCategories::with('products')->findOrFail( $subcatId );
        return View::make('site.single_subcategory', [
            'dual' => $dual,
            'dual_products' => $dual_products
        ]);
}
```

This is my view

```
@foreach($dual as $dual_info)

    <h3>{{ $dual_info['dual_sub_cat_name'] }}</h3>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>   

                    @foreach($dual_products->products as $i => $product)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $product['title'] }}</td>                                                  
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
@endforeach
```

This is what I have in my model

```
    public function subcategory()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('SubCategories', 'sub_cat_id');
    }

    public function products()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('Product', 'dual_sub_cat_id');
    }
```

Tables looks like this

```
 // dual_category
dual_sub_cat_id sub_cat_id dual_sub_cat_name 
   1               1         test 1
   2               1         test 2

// sub_category
sub_cat_id   sub_cat_name
     1          name 1

// products 
product_id   sub_cat_id    dual_sub_cat_id
   1             1               1 
   2             1               2
```

From table `products` I have 2 products in same sub-category and when I open sub category with sub_cat_id = 1 I want to see on page

```
test 1
product_id 1

test 2
product_id 2
```

But I see

```
test 1
product_id 1

test 2
product_id 1
```

UPDATE with Models DualSubCategories Model

```
public function subcategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('SubCategories', 'sub_cat_id');
}

public function products()
{

   return $this->hasMany('Product', 'dual_sub_cat_id');
}
```

SubCategories Model

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'category_id');
}

public function products()
{

   return $this->hasMany('Product', 'sub_cat_id');
}
```

Products Model

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Categories', 'category_id');
}
```

Comment: How is the data being fetched from the database?

Comment: I've updated my question with parts of the Models which I use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things going wrong:

You do a loop and a nested loop. When the upper loop loops for a second time, it executes the inner loop with the same data as the first loop. The `$dual_products` does not change a second or third time. It is not dependent on the upper loop.

But that does not explain why you see one product. In your controller, you call `$dual_products = DualSubCategories::with('products')->findOrFail( $subcatId );`. That fetches one (findOrFail) *DualSubCategory* with the ID of the *SubCategory*. This does not fail because you called it with `sub_cat_id = 1` and, coincidentally, that ID exists in the database.

If your relations are set-up right, this should work:

*Controller*

```
<?php
$dual = DualSubCategories::where('sub_cat_id', $subcatId)->with('products')->get();
return View::make('site.single_subcategory', ['dual' => $dual]);
```

We get the DualSubcategories with the products eager-loaded and assign that to the view.

*View*

```
@foreach($dual as $dual_info)
    <h3>{{ $dual_info->dual_sub_cat_name }}</h3>
        @foreach($dual_info->products as $i => $product)
            {{ $product->title }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

In the view we loop over the DualSubcategories and display the name. Every loop, we loop over the products in that DualSubcategory and display it's title. (I've removed your formatting for clarity)

Comment: Oh, so close.. Thanks a lot for the help. Thats do the trick.